# TiffBitmapEncoder Save(Stream) is slow saving file to nework share

Tags: vb.net, performance, vpn

We have a wpf application that saves an InkCanvas image to a tiff file, via a TiffBitmapEncoder.

The encoder save is fast when saving the file to the local PC and to a network share on the lan, in our devlopment environment, but it is super slow for the customer, saving from their PC application to a network share over VPN, or over wan. A save from our development environment to the customer's share over VPN is slow the same way.

As an example of "slow": a 1mb tiff file takes over a minute to save to the share via the encoder. Same file is saved to the PC in a second. A windows explorer copy from PC to the share, over VPN, takes 2-3 seconds.

Is this a bad approach, to do a save over the network, directly via the Save method in the encoder, or could there be something else going on?

Should our application 1st save to the PC, then copy the file to the share? But then there is overhead handling the multiple copies, etc.

Thanks much!

Here is how the code goes:

```
'Create Visual Brush of UIElement.
Dim visualBrush As VisualBrush = New VisualBrush(source)
Dim drawingVisual As DrawingVisual = New DrawingVisual

Using drawingContext As DrawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen
    'Draw image of element.
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, Nothing, New Rect(source.RenderSize))
End Using

'Render the image.
renderTarget.Render(drawingVisual)
Dim encoder As BitmapEncoder

encoder = New TiffBitmapEncoder  
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget))

Using stream As FileStream = New FileStream(strSaveFileFullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    encoder.Save(stream)
End Using
```

Comment: This is common, and usually means the VPN itself is misconfigured or oversubscribed/not adequately provisioned, or that the local internet connection's upload bandwidth is inadequate. There's probably nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: (a) If you create a local copy first, then it has much less chance of being lost than if something goes wrong while it takes ages to save it to a network drive. (b) The encoder might need random access to the file which isn't working well over a network connection. (c) You might as well try the local-save-then-copy method to see if it works better.

Comment: Yeah, think the key here is _over VPN, or over wan_.  As mentioned, save it locally first, then copy that to the destination which can be done via background thread

Comment: But why would a regular file copy take a few seconds, and the encoder save take over a minute? Because of "The encoder might need random access to the file which isn't working well over a network connection." ? Thanks everyone!